# In what order are shared libraries initialized and finalized?

Tags: shared-libraries, destructor, exit, dlopen

The dynamic objects in a process come from several sources:

1. The executable itself
2. Any libraries it requires (`DT_NEEDED` for ELF)
3. Libraries loaded explicitly (`dlopen` or similar)
4. Any libraries required by such explicit loads

They can be unloaded **explicitly** (`dlclose`) or **implicitly** when the process `exit`s, running their finalization (`atexit` functions, static-duration destructors in C++, and `__attribute__((destructor))` functions) in either case.

What determines the order in which the dynamic objects are initialized and finalized in these various cases?  Obviously the last `dlclose` for a library unloads it immediately, but what about its tree of dependencies (some of which might also be dependencies of other loaded libraries)?  What if a library is `dlopen`ed but then unloaded by `exit`?

I tend to expect the usual **reverse** order of initialization, but maybe there's a difference between `DT_NEEDED` and `dlopen` since "plugins" are loaded by the latter and might be expected to depend on the executable's data rather than the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm is the same in all cases. After mapping main executable (or `dlopen`ed library) dynamic linker will execute initialization functions in topological order so that dependencies are initialized before dependents. Note that this may leave the order unspecified in some cases and linker makes arbitrary choice there.

Library destructors are registered in one of it's constructors (via call to `__cxa_atexit`). Registrarion is performed by prepending cumulative library dtor function to a special list inside Glibc. On `exit`, the list is traversed in forward direction so dependent destructors will be called before their dependencies.

Comment: The topological order doesn’t constrain anything mentioned only by `dlopen`.  Is that suborder unspecified?

Comment: @DavisHerring No, if there's no dependency between two libs they may be initialized in arbitrary relative order. Funny enough, I once experimented with fuzzing this ordering and found some bugs in existing programs.

Comment: I believe the actual ordering picture is a bit more complicated by e.g. `DF_1_INITFIRST` and possibly other flags.

Comment: @EmployedRussian Yes but GNU loader supports only one `DF_1_INITFIRST` library and `libpthread` already has it so in practice this flag is unusable in normal libs.